# Can Kruskal stress be used with metric mds?

Tags: machine-learning, multi-dimensional-scaling

On this site([Stress attribute -- sklearn.manifold.MDS / Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428205/stress-attribute-sklearn-manifold-mds-python)), Kruskal stress is used to metric mds. However, looking at the wiki(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), metric mds uses raw stress and non-metric mds uses Kruskal stress.
For this, I'm confusing that Kruskal stress can use metric mds or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kruskal's Stress-1 by passing `normalized_stress` as `True` to `sklearn.manifold.MDS`. But you have to set the `metric` parameter to `False` as well since the stress is only calculated for non-metric MDS. Example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.manifold import MDS

X, _ = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

embedding = MDS(n_components=2, metric=False, normalized_stress=True)
X_transformed = embedding.fit_transform(X[:100])
```